# Saving message after submit in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I have a function which shows a text after submit form and hide form:

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById('form').style.display ='none';
    document.getElementById('thanks').style.display = '';
}
```

Now I want to save this message after refresh site using sessionstorage, but I have no completely idea how it works and I don't understand the idea.

I just want to not give an user option to send another form unless he close his browser.

In html:

```
    <button type="submit"  id="button" onclick="change()">Send</button>
    <input type="reset" id="button">
  </form>
</div>
<h1 id="thanks" style="display:none">Thanks for submit the form!</h1>
```

Comment: I think you can use local storage to store the results and check it everytime user loads the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like so: set the variable in `sessionStorage` in your `change()` function; and render the elements conditionally, depending on this variable set:

```
window.onload = isChange;

function change() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('change', true);

    isChange();
}

function isChange() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('change')) {
        document.getElementById('form').style.display ='none';
        document.getElementById('thanks').style.display = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('form').style.display ='';
        document.getElementById('thanks').style.display = 'none'n
    }
}
```

Comment: @KubaDisko Please mark it as the correct answer if it helped, thanks